# Asp.Net OuputCache does effect JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, outputcache, adsense

I use Asp.net 4 c# and Page OutPut Cache IN MEMORY for optimizing performances.

For my understanding all the HTML generated by Server Controls will be cached for my page (in memory).

If in my Web Page I use references to CSS and JAVASCRIPT Files, example Google Adsense or others.

**How Page OutPut Cache behaves?**

Even my JAVASCRIPT will be cached?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Page level, or **output caching**, caches the HTML output of dynamic requests to ASP.NET Web pages
>
> With output caching, the final rendered HTML of the page is cached. When the same page is requested again, the control objects are not created, the page life cycle doesn't start, and none of your code executes. Instead, the cached HTML is served. Clearly, output caching gets the theoretical maximum performance increase, because all the overhead of your code is sidestepped.

Comment: even if not generated by the server controls?

Comment: Yes all the html that comes back from the server.

Comment: To be honest MSDN definition does not seems clear to me; if I change the CSS in my site before (external), refresh the cache of the browser before the time expiration for the cache, the CSS is updated and the html for the server side component it is not. It seems to be that MSD validation is valid only for code generated by the Server ONLY, I just would like have a confirmation. Thanks for your time.

Comment: if your css is part of your html (inline style) it will be cached. If you have a external css, OutputCache does not do this.